# Dell Precision M6700 with failed battery does not detect discrete GPU

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, battery, dell-precision

I have a dell m6700 laptop with AMD M6000 graphics. Battery seems to be dead. Running on Direct AC power.

Couple of days ago, the laptop booted on Intel HD 4000, windows device manager saying GPU is disconnected - visible under hidden devices.

[image: Windows Device Manager]

On running boot time Dell Diagnostics, it clearly said that the battery is not able to supply power to the GPU.

I removed the battery and still the laptop boots on Intel HD 4000. GPU missing. There have been couple of times when the bios did detect the GPU. Totally random.

Now the bios is only booting on Intel HD even on direct AC Power (battery removed). HDMI port does not work either, VGA is working. Weird.

Any idea why the GPU won't start when on direct AC power?

**EDIT** - GPU came back up just before I was about to go to bed (random restart). **Battery is inserted (dead though). HDMI port works now**. Ran GPU Diagnostic Tests - All Passed

http://www.dell.com/support/home/IN/en/inbsd1/product-support/servicetag/FND0ZW1/diagnose/showresults/FND0ZW1795C26D8F27747339D74B824AFDE355D#diagcompleted

Comment: Maybe the AC adapter if failing and cannot output enough amps? I would test with a known good ac adapter.

Comment: Well I have 2 AC adapters, same problem. Don't think they would fail simultaneously with the battery.

Comment: Strange issue I have never seen before.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dell Precision M6700 has an MXM graphics card slot. It's possible that the graphics card has somehow slipped out of the slot or has failed.

Open up the laptop and see if the graphics card is properly seated. Also check for physical damage to the card and/or slot. If reseating the card does not help, you may need to replace it.

**Edit:** Your update further supports the theory that your graphics card is poorly seated. Again, open the computer and make sure it is. You may need to clean out the slot contacts if the card is indeed firmly secured in the slot.

Comment: Is there any way this could be linked to the battery? The battery had been failing for quite a while now. There were some warnings earlier.

Comment: I'm not too sure but I kinda doubt it. The card should still be present (even if disabled) if the machine was running on a functioning battery.

Comment: So, the gpu came back up just now. Done some tests, pls check edit.