# Fix Bluetooth for Dell Precision M6700

Tags: usb, laptop, mouse, bluetooth

For some reason Bluetooth is virtually dead on my mother's Dell M6700.

The laptop is old but adequate desktop replacement for checking email, news, social media, watching YouTube and videoconferencing.

Some time ago the wired USB mouse on my mother's old laptop deteriorated and no other mouse would work. USB seems busted, few ports even have enough power to light up mouse. So I bought her a Bluetooth mouse. It worked a few days then Bluetooth disappeared from the settings and gets hidden in the Device manager. USB mouse stopped working too.

Windows 10 (64) with dual boot Lubuntu  (says insufficient GPU for Windows 11)

What I tried so far:

- After removing driver Bluetooth might work several min after reboot, then the Bluetooth indicator as well as Bluetooth on/off option in settings disappear. Sometimes, when Bluetooth indicator lights up for a few minutes after reboot mouse works sometimes not.
- Hardware Aeroplane mode switch does not help.
- Fast startup switched off.
- Bitdefender Antivirus replaced with Avast free, scan found no viruses
- Windows updates says system is up-to-date (Windows 11 incompatible hardware)
- Dell updating software says all drivers up to date.
- The dead battery is removed. (The laptop is used only as a desktop replacement)
- Sometimes battery removal/insert brings back Bluetooth, sometimes it blocks the system
- There could be situation when Bluetooth indicator lights up but mouse do not work and no Bluetooth in Device Manager

Once mouse spontaneously started to work during a Zoom meeting, another time while starting a download, but could be coincidence.

Laptop touch-pad works, but not as comfortable

I consider to use some auxiliary Android device to connect the mouse but hope there is an easier solution

Is there a chance a Windows reinstall can help? I had some bad experience with Windows reinstall on a laptop before, and considering no USB port is available I am wary to take risks

---

**Update(s)**: I reset the energy consumption from performance to economical and disabled few unused ports. I followed a comment suggestion that i7 is a power hog and an older question about [battery removal disabling M6700's discrete GPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1112103/dell-precision-m6700-with-failed-battery-does-not-detect-discrete-gpu), which make me think that without the battery the power supply might struggle with powering auxiliary hardware. There are BIOS options to reduce the amount of cores or disable hyper-threading, I may try that too. Few time when Bluetooth disappeared I removed or put back the dead battery, and Bluetooth reappears. It seems faster than going for reboot/driver delete. Yet on recent attempts battery removal/insert  turned off the laptop, not sure what was done differently.

Also I am trying using old Android cell phone with Unified Remote app as back up solution if laptop's Bluetooth goes south. Surprisingly, cell screen it is more comfortable than build-in track-pad. I hear some remote mouse apps respond to tilting of the cell but failed to install it.

Update 19.03.2024 Record 'green stripe' - a week ago, after some break a mysterious message appeared and the Bluetooth mouse work fine since then. I keep my fingers crossed

Comment: Try a Panda USB Bluetooth Card.  I have one.  Should work.

Comment: Sounds like the computer is half-dead already. A new computer might be a more lasting solution.

Comment: If none of the USB ports work well, the power supply and/or battery may be dying. The laptop has an i7, demanding power. Replacement batteries are advertised for US$32 and up. Check the battery status, and replace if needed. It makes much more sense than waiting for the machine to stop completely.

Comment: hrrmm.. `is near dead` .. I believe the proper term is `mostly dead`

Comment: Battery is dead and removed, but she does not need one. This particular laptop is too bulky to use on the go anyway

Comment: She does not like Linux, but seems like same problem. But over weekend I can try to install or reinstall a Bluetooth driver on Linux if it might help

Comment: Most modern laptops cannot actually be turned on or function properly without a battery.

Comment: That's a crazy world we live in

Comment: And, I guess, Dell M6700 inventors were way ahead of their time

Comment: You would be surprised what some 99% isopropyl and soft-bristle toothbrushes can fix.

Answer (score 0):

The number of issues with this computer indicate to me there are multiple deteriorating components inside it. Power connections are a good place to start.

If the internal Bluetooth chip is actually dead-dead, an external USB Bluetooth receiver should be a good solution, but your failing USB ports makes that not possible right now.

The laptop has enough problems that a proper solution is that the laptop should be taken apart and carefully inspected and refreshed/refurbished. This will solve your USB issues, and probably your Bluetooth issue too, and if not, it will enable you using a cheap replacement USB Bluetooth adapter as a good solution.